# Spring scheduler collision when using fixedDelay

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks, spring-scheduled

As it's written in official documentation

> .. fixed delay, meaning that the period will be measured from the
>   completion time of each preceding invocation

But i have troubles with it. My code with fixedDelayString

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${schedule.time:2000}")
public void tasksScheduler() {
    LOG.trace("starts");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(new Random().nextInt(5000));
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    LOG.trace("completed");
}
```

It has proper order in my local machine

```
2015-09-22 10:16:11,098 TRACE r.u.s.i.AutoRegistrationAccountScheduler [pool-3-thread-1] starts
2015-09-22 10:16:12,707 TRACE r.u.s.i.AutoRegistrationAccountScheduler [pool-3-thread-1] completed
2015-09-22 10:16:15,708 TRACE r.u.s.i.AutoRegistrationAccountScheduler [pool-3-thread-1] starts
2015-09-22 10:16:18,768 TRACE r.u.s.i.AutoRegistrationAccountScheduler [pool-3-thread-1] completed
2015-09-22 10:16:21,769 TRACE r.u.s.i.AutoRegistrationAccountScheduler [pool-3-thread-1] starts
2015-09-22 10:16:23,882 TRACE r.u.s.i.AutoRegistrationAccountScheduler [pool-3-thread-1] completed
2015-09-22 10:16:26,882 TRACE r.u.s.i.AutoRegistrationAccountScheduler [pool-3-thread-1] starts
2015-09-22 10:16:31,073 TRACE r.u.s.i.AutoRegistrationAccountScheduler [pool-3-thread-1] completed
2015-09-22 10:16:34,074 TRACE r.u.s.i.AutoRegistrationAccountScheduler [pool-3-thread-1] starts
```

But i have collisions in my servel. Server logs below

```
2015-09-22 05:26:21,315 TRACE r.u.s.i.AutoRegistrationAccountScheduler [pool-3-thread-1] starts
2015-09-22 05:26:25,593 TRACE r.u.s.i.AutoRegistrationAccountScheduler [pool-3-thread-1] completed
2015-09-22 05:26:28,594 TRACE r.u.s.i.AutoRegistrationAccountScheduler [pool-3-thread-1] starts
2015-09-22 05:26:32,169 TRACE r.u.s.i.AutoRegistrationAccountScheduler [pool-3-thread-1] completed
2015-09-22 05:26:35,170 TRACE r.u.s.i.AutoRegistrationAccountScheduler [pool-3-thread-1] starts
2015-09-22 05:26:38,608 TRACE r.u.s.i.AutoRegistrationAccountScheduler [pool-3-thread-1] completed
2015-09-22 05:26:41,608 TRACE r.u.s.i.AutoRegistrationAccountScheduler [pool-3-thread-1] starts
2015-09-22 05:26:44,341 TRACE r.u.s.i.AutoRegistrationAccountScheduler [pool-3-thread-1] completed
2015-09-22 05:26:47,342 TRACE r.u.s.i.AutoRegistrationAccountScheduler [pool-3-thread-1] starts
2015-09-22 05:26:49,808 TRACE r.u.s.i.AutoRegistrationAccountScheduler [pool-6-thread-1] starts
2015-09-22 05:26:50,400 TRACE r.u.s.i.AutoRegistrationAccountScheduler [pool-6-thread-1] completed
2015-09-22 05:26:50,734 TRACE r.u.s.i.AutoRegistrationAccountScheduler [pool-3-thread-1] completed
2015-09-22 05:26:53,401 TRACE r.u.s.i.AutoRegistrationAccountScheduler [pool-6-thread-1] starts
2015-09-22 05:26:53,735 TRACE r.u.s.i.AutoRegistrationAccountScheduler [pool-3-thread-1] starts
2015-09-22 05:26:54,074 TRACE r.u.s.i.AutoRegistrationAccountScheduler [pool-6-thread-1] completed
2015-09-22 05:26:56,267 TRACE r.u.s.i.AutoRegistrationAccountScheduler [pool-3-thread-1] completed
2015-09-22 05:26:57,075 TRACE r.u.s.i.AutoRegistrationAccountScheduler [pool-6-thread-1] starts
2015-09-22 05:26:58,604 TRACE r.u.s.i.AutoRegistrationAccountScheduler [pool-6-thread-1] completed
2015-09-22 05:26:59,268 TRACE r.u.s.i.AutoRegistrationAccountScheduler [pool-3-thread-1] starts
2015-09-22 05:27:01,605 TRACE r.u.s.i.AutoRegistrationAccountScheduler [pool-6-thread-1] starts
2015-09-22 05:27:03,176 TRACE r.u.s.i.AutoRegistrationAccountScheduler [pool-6-thread-1] completed
2015-09-22 05:27:03,375 TRACE r.u.s.i.AutoRegistrationAccountScheduler [pool-3-thread-1] completed
2015-09-22 05:27:06,177 TRACE r.u.s.i.AutoRegistrationAccountScheduler [pool-6-thread-1] starts
2015-09-22 05:27:06,376 TRACE r.u.s.i.AutoRegistrationAccountScheduler [pool-3-thread-1] starts
2015-09-22 05:27:07,253 TRACE r.u.s.i.AutoRegistrationAccountScheduler [pool-6-thread-1] completed
2015-09-22 05:27:10,254 TRACE r.u.s.i.AutoRegistrationAccountScheduler [pool-6-thread-1] starts
2015-09-22 05:27:10,691 TRACE r.u.s.i.AutoRegistrationAccountScheduler [pool-3-thread-1] completed
2015-09-22 05:27:12,737 TRACE r.u.s.i.AutoRegistrationAccountScheduler [pool-6-thread-1] completed
2015-09-22 05:27:13,692 TRACE r.u.s.i.AutoRegistrationAccountScheduler [pool-3-thread-1] starts
2015-09-22 05:27:15,450 TRACE r.u.s.i.AutoRegistrationAccountScheduler [pool-3-thread-1] completed
2015-09-22 05:27:15,738 TRACE r.u.s.i.AutoRegistrationAccountScheduler [pool-6-thread-1] starts
2015-09-22 05:27:16,940 TRACE r.u.s.i.AutoRegistrationAccountScheduler [pool-6-thread-1] completed
2015-09-22 05:27:18,450 TRACE r.u.s.i.AutoRegistrationAccountScheduler [pool-3-thread-1] starts
2015-09-22 05:27:19,941 TRACE r.u.s.i.AutoRegistrationAccountScheduler [pool-6-thread-1] starts
2015-09-22 05:27:20,727 TRACE r.u.s.i.AutoRegistrationAccountScheduler [pool-3-thread-1] completed
2015-09-22 05:27:22,741 TRACE r.u.s.i.AutoRegistrationAccountScheduler [pool-6-thread-1] completed
```

I tried to define custom scheduler as

```
<task:annotation-driven scheduler="myScheduler"/>
<task:scheduler id="myScheduler" pool-size="1"/>
```

But it doesn't help me, collisions still exist

```
2015-09-22 10:50:29, [myScheduler-1] starts
2015-09-22 10:50:32, [myScheduler-1] completed
2015-09-22 10:50:34, [myScheduler-1] starts
2015-09-22 10:50:36, [myScheduler-1] completed
2015-09-22 10:50:38, [myScheduler-1] starts
2015-09-22 10:50:39, [myScheduler-1] completed
2015-09-22 10:50:41, [myScheduler-1] starts
2015-09-22 10:50:42, [myScheduler-1] starts
2015-09-22 10:50:43, [myScheduler-1] completed
2015-09-22 10:50:45, [myScheduler-1] starts
2015-09-22 10:50:47, [myScheduler-1] completed
2015-09-22 10:50:47, [myScheduler-1] completed
2015-09-22 10:50:49, [myScheduler-1] starts
2015-09-22 10:50:49, [myScheduler-1] starts
2015-09-22 10:50:49, [myScheduler-1] completed
2015-09-22 10:50:51, [myScheduler-1] starts
2015-09-22 10:50:51, [myScheduler-1] completed
2015-09-22 10:50:53, [myScheduler-1] starts
2015-09-22 10:50:54, [myScheduler-1] completed
2015-09-22 10:50:56, [myScheduler-1] starts
2015-09-22 10:50:57, [myScheduler-1] completed
2015-09-22 10:50:59, [myScheduler-1] starts
2015-09-22 10:51:00, [myScheduler-1] completed
2015-09-22 10:51:02, [myScheduler-1] starts
2015-09-22 10:51:03, [myScheduler-1] completed
2015-09-22 10:51:04, [myScheduler-1] completed
2015-09-22 10:51:05, [myScheduler-1] starts
2015-09-22 10:51:06, [myScheduler-1] starts
2015-09-22 10:51:10, [myScheduler-1] completed
2015-09-22 10:51:10, [myScheduler-1] completed
2015-09-22 10:51:12, [myScheduler-1] starts
2015-09-22 10:51:12, [myScheduler-1] starts
2015-09-22 10:51:16, [myScheduler-1] completed
2015-09-22 10:51:17, [myScheduler-1] completed
2015-09-22 10:51:18, [myScheduler-1] starts
2015-09-22 10:51:19, [myScheduler-1] starts
2015-09-22 10:51:19, [myScheduler-1] completed
2015-09-22 10:51:19, [myScheduler-1] completed
2015-09-22 10:51:21, [myScheduler-1] starts
```

Why is fixedDelay work so? How can i ensure that there will be no collisions?

Comment: Its nothing to do with your server machine. If you see the logs then you can see two different thread pools are active currently i.e. pool-3 & pool-6 and they are running on there own thread pool with respective fixed delays references.

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand what you want to say. Yes, i see two thread pools pool-3 & pool-6, but i don't know how it relates to timing. As i think when arise time's expire event spring takes one of existing thread from thread pool and invoke method using this thread.  Am not i right?

Comment: I tried to define custom scheduler but it doesn't help me, collisions still exist. I've updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to twice initialization of application context. I found out it when i added log message to constructor of my bean.

```
public AutoRegistrationAccountScheduler() {
    LOG.trace("I'm initialized! Time = " + new Date() + ", this = " + this);
}
```

And also there were two lines in my logs

```
2015-09-23 03:38:07,917 INFO o.s.w.c.ContextLoader [localhost-startStop-1] Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
....
2015-09-23 03:38:22,112 INFO o.s.w.c.ContextLoader [pool-3-thread-1] Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
```

Then i decided to compare tomcat configurations (local and production) and found there unnecessary lines that is cause of my second web application's initialization

```
<Context path="/" docBase="ROOT">
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
</Context>
```

After removing this lines all works as i expected.